# File pointer null in c

Tags: c, file-handling, null-pointer

I am a learning file handling in C. I tried implementing a program but no matter what I do the file pointer is still null.

I checked the spelling, the directory, even tried adding and removing .txt extension but I still don't get what is wrong with this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr1;
    char filename[100], c;

    printf("Enter the filename to open for reading: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    fptr1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fptr1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", filename);
    }
    do {
        c = fgetc(fptr1);
        printf("%c", c);
    } while (c != EOF);
    fclose(fptr1);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share what you've tried so far.

Comment: I checked if I misspelled the file name, checked if the it is in the same directory. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: did you check global variable errno is set to indicate the error?

Comment: It is a mistake in pasting the code. It compiled and ran with no problem. Only that it is a null pointer each time.

Comment: I am just learning C. So, I have no idea about errno

Comment: Change the line `printf("Cannot open file %s \n", filename);` to `perror(filename);` to get a hint of _why_ it can't be opened.

Comment: OK I will try and say

Comment: Btw, `scanf("%s", filename);` looks like the wrong tool since it will only read a _word_. If your filename contains whitespaces, it will be cut short. Use `fgets(filename, sizeof filename, stdin)` instead - and **always** check the return values from functions that can fail, like `scanf` and `fgets` can.

Comment: Note that `scanf("%s", filename);` will only read a single word. Therefore, if your file name contains spaces, only the characters before the first space will be stored in `filename`. If you want to read an entire line of input, I recommend that you use the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead and then [remove the newline character from the input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/12149471), like this: `fgets( filename, sizeof filename, stdin ); filename[strcspn(filename,"\n")] = '\0';` Note that the function `strcspn` requires you to `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: If OP uses `fgets` without removing the newline character, then `fopen` will likely fail due to not finding the file name.

Comment: Okay... Thanks to perror(filename); I discovered that you have to add .txt extension and the problem with my code is not that the pointer is null but rather the first character is EOF so the file can't be read. As for why it is EOF I have no idea.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes, true.

Comment: @RupaTS We can't say anything about that because you haven't shown how you read from the file.

Comment: I guess that you are using Microsoft Windows which hides the extensions of file names by default. If that is the case, then I suggest that you change this setting in Windows, so that it shows the extensions.

Comment: To those who have pointed out the problem with scanf, I don't have any space in my filename. In fact as this is for learning purpose I just named it ftest1.txt. But considering the fact that people use space when naming files, I must really keep this point in mind.

Comment: Note that generally, you should not change the question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers. Your new problem with `fgetc` is a different problem. However, because you question does not have any existing answers, in my opinion, it is acceptable for you to change the question. Otherwise, it would be appropriate to post a second question instead.

Comment: _... the pointer is null but rather the first character is EOF so the file can't be read._ I'm quite dubious of this claim. Can you add your text file to the question? Are you sure it's just a simple text file,, no weird encoding?

Comment: Should I close this question and create a new one?

Comment: @RupaTS: In this case, I believe it is ok for you to reuse the existing question, because it has no answers, only comments.

Comment: Yeah. The text file just contains a sentence, "File Handling in C test trial."

Comment: Note: `c` should be an `int`, not a `char`. Your loop is also wrong in that it will try to print the character even when EOF is returned

Comment: Yeah I tried changing char to int. It still stays the same.

Comment: Wait a min. I am typing in my phone. I will compare and see if I made any mistakes

Comment: you'll also need to add the code that reads and closes the file in an `else` block. If `fptr1 == NULL` you print out an error, but then go on and try to read the file anyway. What if you hardcode the file name rather than getting it from user input, same problem?

Comment: Yeah I changed the ch to c ‍♀️

Comment: And no change if I directly give the filename instead of user input

Comment: Depending on which platform you are using, a `char` is not guaranteed to be able to store the value `EOF`. For this reason, and also at least one other reason, you should make `c` an `int`, which is guaranteed to be able to store the value `EOF`. Note that the function `fgetc` returns a value of type `int`, not `char`. Once you have determined that `c` does not hold the value `EOF`, you can treat it as a normal `char` value.

Comment: Yeah I tried changing that, it went from EOF to -1, which I discovered still means EOF. So I changed it back to char.

Comment: @RupaTS: Even if the value `EOF` is representable on your platform as a `char`, I still recommend that you make `c` an `int`, because otherwise, you will not be able to distinguish the special value `EOF` from an actual value of a character code. Therefore, that value will be ambiguous in certain situations.

Comment: Ok I am giving up on this for today. I will look at it tomorrow. Maybe after waking up I will grow a brain and be able to solve whatever this thing's problem is. Thank you guys for your help. Thanks to you I learnt quite a bit.

Comment: @yano: Instead of enclosing the remainder of the function `main` in an `else` block, I think it would be easier to simply add the line `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` after `printf("Cannot open file %s \n", filename);`. This will terminate the program immediately. Note that the function `exit` and the macro constant `EXIT_FAILURE` both require `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @RupaTS Some of the things mentioned here could make it into [this](https://godbolt.org/z/qe3bYYWr9) for reading text files.

Comment: If `c` gets the value `EOF`, then you will attempt to print that value with `printf("%c", c);`. This may print a garbage character, because the special value `EOF` is not an actual character code. For this reason, I suggest that you change your `do`...`while` loop to a `while` loop, like this: `while ( (c=fgetc(fptr1)) != EOF ) { printf( "%c", c ); }`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code it works fine , **you just have to add (filename.txt)** as your input like **(myfile.txt)**

well i changed some in your code to make it more simpler ,so here is the changed sections

**First** from this

```
 if (fptr1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", filename);
    }
```

to this

```
 if (fptr1 == NULL)
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", filename);
```

Because when you have only **one line that execute after the condition is true , you can get ride of the { }**

also i changed the **( do while )** to **( while )**
**Second** from this

```
 do {
        c = fgetc(fptr1);
        printf("%c", c);
    } while (c != EOF);
```

to this

```
    while(!feof(fptr1)){
        c = fgetc(fptr1);
        printf("%c",c);
    }
```

Here the line **feof** is a function that means **the end of file**

We are checking if its **NOT the end of file ( !feof )** , if thats true then we can read from the file and print the result .
the loop ends when **c = EOF .**

and thats it.

**NOTE** : your file name **should be without spaces ( myfile.txt )** and **not (my file.txt)** because we are using **scanf() function** , it stoppes when countering a space ( blank space ) , so keep that in mind.

Comment: The function `feof` specifies whether a function call to `fgetc` **has already failed** due to end-of-file. It does not necessarily specify whether the next call to `fgetc` **will fail**. Therefore, your use of `feof` is wrong, because you will attempt to print one `EOF` character returned by `fgetc`. I suggest that you read this for further information: [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/12149471)

Comment: For the reason stated in my previous comment, I think the best solution would be `while ( (c=fgetc(fptr1)) != EOF ) { printf( "%c", c ); }`.